# How to Loop next element in hashmap

Tags: java, for-loop, hashmap

I have a set of strings like this

```
A_2007-04, A_2007-09, A_Agent, A_Daily, A_Execute, A_Exec, B_Action, B_HealthCheck
```

I want output as:

```
Key = A, Value = [2007-04,2007-09,Agent,Execute,Exec]
Key = B, Value = [Action,HealthCheck]
```

I'm using HashMap to do this

```
pckg:{A,B}
count:total no of strings
reports:set of strings
```

Logic I used is nested loop:

```
for (String l : reports[i]) {
    for (String r : pckg) {
        String[] g = l.split("_");
        if (g[0].equalsIgnoreCase(r)) {
            report.add(g[1]);
            dirFiles.put(g[0], report);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting output as

```
Key = A, Value = [2007-04,2007-09,Agent,Execute,Exec]
```

How to get second key?
Can someone suggest logic for this?

Comment: What is the value of pckg?

Comment: First, your variable names are confusing. You should give them meaningful names. Second, what is the type of `pckg`? Seems weird that you are looping through the `pckg` variable while in the for loop of `reports[i]`

Comment: with P_Action and P_HealthCheck, you cannot get Key = B, Value = [Action,HealthCheck], you can only get it with Key = P so pckg should be:{A,P} not {A,B}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of raw code this should do what I think you are trying to achieve:

```
// Create a collection of String any way you like, but for testing
// I've simply split a flat string into an array.
String flatString = "A_2007-04,A_2007-09,A_Agent,A_Daily,A_Execute,A_Exec,"
        + "P_Action,P_HealthCheck";
String[] reports = flatString.split(",");

Map<String, List<String>> mapFromReportKeyToValues = new HashMap<>();

for (String report : reports) {
    int underscoreIndex = report.indexOf("_");
    String key = report.substring(0, underscoreIndex);
    String newValue = report.substring(underscoreIndex + 1);
    List<String> existingValues = mapFromReportKeyToValues.get(key);
    if (existingValues == null) {
        // This key hasn't been seen before, so create a new list
        // to contain values which belong under this key.
        existingValues = new ArrayList<>();
        mapFromReportKeyToValues.put(key, existingValues);
    }
    existingValues.add(newValue);
}

System.out.println("Generated map:\n" + mapFromReportKeyToValues);
```

Though I recommend tidying it up and organising it into a method or methods as fits your project code.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you use Java 8, it can be done using [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) to initialize the `List` of values when it is a new key as next:

```
List<String> tokens = Arrays.asList(
    "A_2007-04", "A_2007-09", "A_Agent", "A_Daily", "A_Execute", 
    "A_Exec", "P_Action", "P_HealthCheck"
);
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
for (String token : tokens) {
    String[] g = token.split("_");
    map.computeIfAbsent(g[0], key -> new ArrayList<>()).add(g[1]);
}
```

Comment: +1 for bringing `computeIfAbsent` to my attention. I'd been wondering for some time why Java core hadn't made it easier to handle a map whose values were themselves a collection, and this fills the gap nicely.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (String l : reports[i]) {
        String[] g = l.split("_");
        for (String r : pckg) {
            if (g[0].equalsIgnoreCase(r)) {
                report = dirFiles.get(g[0]);
                if(report == null){ report = new ArrayList<String>(); } //create new report
                report.add(g[1]);
                dirFiles.put(g[0], report);
            }
        }
}
```

- Removed the `else` part of the `if` condition. You are using break there which exits the inner loop and you never get to evaluate the keys beyond first key.
- Added checking for existing values. As suggested by Orin2005.
- Also I have moved the statement `String[] g = l.split("_");` outside inner loop so that it doesn't get executed multiple times.

Comment: In the line `dirFiles.put(g[0], report);`, I think you need to account for everything that is already in the `HashMap` for that key aswell. so it should be `dirFiles.put(g[0], dirFiles.get(g[0]).addAll(report));` or something, depending on what the value of `report` is.

Comment: I assume report is List of Strings and dirFiles is HashMap with key-type String and value-type List of Strings. In that case it'd work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this with `Map<String, ArrayList<String>>` will be another good approach I think:

```
    String reports[] = {"A_2007-04", "A_2007-09", "A_Agent", "A_Daily", 
                        "A_Execute", "A_Exec", "P_Action", "P_HealthCheck"};
    Map<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (String rep : reports) {

        String s[] = rep.split("_");
        String prefix = s[0], suffix = s[1];
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        if (map.containsKey(prefix)) {
            list = map.get(prefix);
        }

        list.add(suffix);
        map.put(prefix, list);
    }

    // Print
    for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        ArrayList<String> valueList = entry.getValue();
        System.out.println(key + " " + valueList);
    }
```